# jquery deffered with a random number of animations

Tags: jquery

I've got *x* number of animations running on a random timer.  I also have code that needs to run after all the animations are complete.

I thought to use deferred, but it doesn't seem to be running the way I hoped it was going to.  Here's a link (you may have to run it a few times for it to not work):

http://jsfiddle.net/N8nFU/

Code:

```
var callback = function() {
    alert('done!');
};

var animations;
for (var i = 0; i < $('div').length; i++) {
    var random = Math.random() * (800 - 100) + 100;
    animations = $('div').eq(i).slideUp(random);
}

$.when(animations).done(callback);
```

Any suggestions on how to wait for the callback to be called once all the animations are complete?

Comment: The code above is the corrected version. It would be nice to have the incorrect version in there, for the next guy who comes along.

Comment: @joshjs: You are right, I mistakenly copied the wrong version. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are always overriding the `animations` variable. So the object you pass to `$.when` will be the one from the last iteration.

Add them to an array and call `$.when` with that array:

```
var animations = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $('div').length; i++) {
    var random = Math.random() * (800 - 100) + 100;
    animations.push($('div').eq(i).slideUp(random));
}

$.when.apply($, animations).done(callback);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/N8nFU/4/)

**Reference:** [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply)